# reusing code that Formats Objects for display

Tags: c#, .net, formatting

I have a list of objects that are instances of a class.
I want to format them for display and i want the code that formats the display to be reusable.
So it can be used in a .aspx page and when exporting the data to excel.

I started off creating a function that returns an anonymous class object with all the fields of the class formatted.

```
public Object GetForDisplay()
        {
            return new
            {
                RecordNum,
                ID,
                Value = Value.HasValue?  Value.Value.ToString("0.##"): "-",
                ...
            };
        }
```

But this did not allow me to access the properties when i needed slight changes in them.

My next try was to return a `Dictionary<String,Object>` with all the fields (The string being the field name).

```
public Dictionary<String, Object> GetForDisplay()
        {
            return new Dictionary<String, Object>
            {
                {"RecordNum", RecordNum},
                { "ID", ID },
                { "Value ",  Value.HasValue?  Value.Value.ToString("0.##"): "-"},
             }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this? would you create a new class just to hold the formatted data?

Comment: Can't you simply override `ToString()` method of every class so you can pass it to any function to show on screen?

Comment: You need to learn how to develop with ASP.NET properly... that is your problem, not the one above but the fact that you don't yet know how to use ASP.NET. For the case above, you would write user controls or Web controls. See, for instance, http://www.netomatix.com/development/usercontrols1.aspx. Good luck.

Comment: Having your class implement IFormattable and using a custom IFormatProvider and ICustomFormatter should help when it comes to display tricky/possible-null/combinated values